# concatenated with default string ( Procedure Oracle )

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure, concatenation

I am newbie with Oracle. Withe the table has firstname and lastname consisted (email is empty). My question is to write the PL/SQL( Procedure ) with those requirements.

a) first letter from firstname is concatenated with lastname (Dan Smilze   - - >   DSmilze);

b) all the accents are removed (ä - - > a, ö - - > o, …);

c)  if  two equal emails appear, then instead of one letter from firstname 2 first letters are used (Dan Smilze - - >  DaSmilze);

e) Username is concatenated with  „@gmail.com“

Result should be:

```
FIRSTNAME     LASTNAME    EMAIL

Dan           Smilze      DSmilze@gmail.com
Ceo           Jürisoo     CJurisoo@gmail.com
```

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_email
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE  emails set Email = (select CONCAT(substr(firstname,1,1),convert(lastname,'US7ASCII')) from email_lphanvan);
END merge_email;
```

I know that my code was not enough and wrong somehow. May you help me to understand this procedure? Thank you so much!

Comment: What happens with names like `Ed O’Neill`?

Comment: I does not work in this case. Just popular names in my country btw. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: What happens if you have two "Peter Smith"?

Comment: if two equal emails appear, then instead of one letter from firstname 2 first letters are used (Dan Smilze - - > DaSmilze);  @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: So what happen if you have 4 Dan Smilze?

Comment: So what if you have 'Pat Smith', 'Patrick Smith' and 'Paddy Smith'? What email addresses would you expect to see?

Comment: In this case, I just think for 2 equal emails. For other cases, I would think about using Exception. @Kacper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that you had to wait that long. It is not the nicest solution but it works:

```
create table emails (name varchar2(20), surname varchar2(20), email varchar2(40));
insert into emails values ('Jan', 'Kowalski','');
insert into emails values ('Jan', 'Nowak','');
insert into emails values ('Jan', 'Ścigalski','');
insert into emails values ('Stefan', 'Kowalski','');
insert into emails values ('Stefan', 'Kowalski','');
insert into emails values ('Stefan', 'Kowalski','');
insert into emails values ('Józef', 'Błazen','');
insert into emails values ('Jan', 'Nowak','');
commit;

begin
for x in (select rowid, name, surname, row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by name) r from emails) loop
UPDATE  emails set Email = convert(substr(x.name,1,x.r),'US7ASCII') || convert(x.surname,'US7ASCII') || '@gmail.com' where rowid = x.rowid;
end loop;
commit;
end;
/
```

If you have any `id` in table please use `id` instead of `rowid`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :))). I will test it.